# Phpmyadmin - error for symbol °

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I seem to have a weird problem with my Phpmyadmin database. When I use the symbol `°` in my table `subject` it gives an error and won't insert, for my table `message` however this doesn't make a difference.

I tried it as a `VARCHAR` and as `TEXT`, but both give errors. The message field is a `TEXT` and doesn't give any errors.

I found this: http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/2156/how-do-i-fix-incorrect-string-value-x-errors-when-running-on-mysql

My outputs are: utf8_general_ci, latin1_swedish_ci, latin1_swedish_ci

**Error:**

```
DB Error #1366

INSERT INTO table SET created=NOW() ,ticketID=7403, subject='FW: Stackoverflow N� 456'

Incorrect string value: 'xB0 4100...' for column 'subject' at row 1
```

Comment: What charset are you using? Depending on the error you may want to make sure you're using UTF-8 general (from memory) or Latin-1 Swedish

Comment: Also, phpMyAdmin's connection might not be set to use UTF-8.

Comment: how can I verify this? But why would it work for message ..?

Comment: Based on the edit the source of the text isn't in UTF-8, most likely the source is in ISO-8859-1 meaning it requires encoding for mySQL to accept it as a valid character, I have worked with a PHP application where the solution was to use `utf8_encode` for every field working with the source email for the script to save to the DB but this would depend on the language you're working with as to what is available to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with a patch supplied by the vendor of my program.

Answer (score 0):

Change Collation of your table to utf8_general_ci

Comment: execute set names utf8;
it sets the client character set variables to utf8. So the values sent from the client program are stored 'as is' in the table because the client character set and the table's character set is the same.

Comment: open sql tab on the right pane of your phpmyadmin... execute "set names utf8;"

Comment: @Tom let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2223/discussion-between-venu-gopal-t-and-tom)